# Login and Validation logical error in flask

Tags: authentication, flask-sqlalchemy, bcrypt, flask-login, password-hash

***My requirement is when i enter the username and passwords saved in my database, the validation should lead me to respective dashboards according to the roles but somehow when i enter id and pass saved in my database or even a random id and pass, i get redirected to the print statement 'Something is wrong'. Here is my code of FRS.py, please tell me what the logic problem is, thanks.***

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user
import bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///FRS_database.db"
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my_secret_key'
db: SQLAlchemy = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
role = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)

def __init__(self, username, password, role):
    self.username = username
    self.role = role
    self.password = password

    # Check if the password is already hashed
    if not password.startswith("$2b$"):
        # Hash the password
        self.password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'),         bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')
    else:
        # Use the existing hashed password
        self.password = password

    def check_password(self, password):
    return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), self.password.encode('utf-8'))


    with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


    @app.route("/")
    def Home():
    return render_template('Login.html')


    @app.route('/Register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    role = request.form['role']

    new_user = User(username=username, password=password, role=role)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/Login')

    return render_template('Register.html')


    @app.route("/Login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    if user and user.check_password(password):
        login_user(user)
        session['username'] = user.username
        session['id'] = user.id
        session['password'] = user.password
        session['role'] = user.role

        if 'role' in session:
            if session['role'] == 'admin':
                return redirect(url_for('admin_dashboard'))
            elif session['role'] == 'student':
                return redirect(url_for('student_dashboard'))
            elif session['role'] == 'faculty':
                return redirect(url_for('faculty_dashboard'))
            else:
                print("Role in session:", session['role'])
        return render_template('Login.html')

    flash('Invalid username or password', 'error')
    return 'something is wrong'

return 'oops'


@app.route('/admin_dashboard')
def admin_dashboard():
if 'role' in session and session['role'] == 'admin':
    return render_template('admin_dashboard.html')
return redirect(url_for('Login'))


@app.route('/student_dashboard')
def student_dashboard():
if 'role' in session and session['role'] == 'student':
    return render_template('student_dashboard.html')
return redirect(url_for('Login'))


@app.route('/faculty_dashboard')
def faculty_dashboard():
if 'role' in session and session['role'] == 'faculty':
    return render_template('faculty_dashboard.html')
return redirect(url_for('Login'))


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
return render_template('Login.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

i've tried almost everything in my knowledge and the problem of redirecting to respective         dashboard still persists. i think there might be something wrong with the login logic or the database